# Why cant i use class methods on object that was created in another class in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

How could I send xmldocument object to a function in another class?
In the example below I didn't get all xmldocument methods and properties to show from scan function.

```
xmldocument xmldoc = new xmldocument();
xmldoc.load(test.xml);

anotherclass axls = new anotherclass();
axls.scan(xmldoc);


public class anotherclass()
{
    public void scan(object xmldoc)  {  some code }
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare `object xmldoc`? As long as `xmldoc` is an object - you can only call the methods `Object` class implements.

Comment: Please post real code. I can tell by the capitalization that this is not such.

Comment: Simply do `public void scan(XmlDocument xmldoc)`

Answer (score 3):

The type you use for a function parameter should be the most restrictive that makes sense. As far as I can tell, your scan method is supposed to work on `XmlDocument`s. So, for instance, change it to be:

```
public class anotherclass()
{
    public void scan(XmlDocument xmldoc)  { // some code }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense will only show you the methods for object as it was declared, it will not show the methods for the class actually held.  In addition, for C# coding, the compiler will not be able to find a method for XmlDocument on a parameter of type Object.

Please change your method signature to take an `XmlDocument` and not an `Object` and you should get the intellisense you are looking for.

The line from [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229015%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to help here is:

> Do use the least-derived parameter type that provides the
>   functionality required by the member.

Comment: It's more than just intellisense. The compiler will not be able to resolve the method either.